# How to initialize instance variables in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need stats in a game that I'm making and I used code from Brackeys(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8GmfoaOB4Y&t=136s), he can only set code in the inspector, but I want to make a database-like manager that assigns stats to every unit in the game in one single script.

```
public class Stat
{

    [SerializeField]
    //public float baseValue;  // Starting value
    public float baseValue;
}
```

```
public class CharacterStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Stat armor;
    void SetArmorToFive(){
    armor = ???
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is keep a reference to every CharacterStats instance in the scene.

Than Create some kind of function that makes you able to set the variables of every CharacterStats instance via the Stat class.

example:

> Global script that holds a reference to all the CharacterStats Instances

```
public class CharacterStatsHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterStats[] characterStats;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterStats = FindObjectsOfType<CharacterStats>();

        foreach(CharacterStats stat in characterStats)
        {
            stat.SetArmorLevel(5);
        }
    }

}
```

> The same script as in the question but with a parameter in the SetArmorLevel function

```
public class CharacterStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Stat armor;
    void SetArmorLevel(int level){
    armor = level;
    }
}
```

> The same stat script

```
public class Stat
{
    [SerializeField]
    //public float baseValue;  // Starting value
    public float baseValue;
}
```

Here is a quick link if you're interested in learning how parameters work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MFiyP0RPW0

Comment: I get an error: Cannot implicity convert type 'float'(int in your sample code) to 'Stat'

Comment: try armor.baseValue = level instaed